# Nginx 1.10 and WordPress 3.6.1 Permalink issue

Tags: wordpress, nginx, permalinks

I have issue with WordPress's permalinks while I am using nginx.
I've tried to add the following line in my nginx's config file, but still I am unable to getting these permalinks to work:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /en/index.php?$args;
}
```

I am getting 404 error, when I enable Permalinks in WordPress control panel.

Here is my nginx conf file, if this could help to investigate the issue, as I've tried almost everything on the web. I guess something in my config  is messing up:

```
server {

        server_name blog.domain.com www.blog.domain.com;

        listen 161.122.20.14;

        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
                ssl_certificate /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/ssl.cert;
                ssl_certificate_key /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/ssl.key;
        }

        server {
                server_name blog.domain.com www.blog.domain.com;

                listen 161.122.20.14:443 ssl http2;

                root /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/public_html;

                index index.html index.htm index.php;

                access_log /var/log/virtualmin/blog.domain.com_access_log;
                error_log /var/log/virtualmin/blog.domain.com_error_log;

        fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
                fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
                fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
                fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
                fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
                fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
                fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/public_html;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
                fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
                fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
                fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/php-nginx/14765596504348.sock/socket;
                }

                location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
                }

                location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
                }

        location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                access_log        off;
                log_not_found     off;
                expires 365d;
                }

                location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
                deny all;
                }

                location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ {
                return 444;
                }

                location ~* \.(pl|cgi|py|sh|lua)\$ {
                return 444;
                }

                location ~ /(\.|wp-config\.php|readme\.html|license\.txt) { deny all; }

        ssl_certificate /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/ssl.cert;
                ssl_certificate_key /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/ssl.key;
                ssl_trusted_certificate /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/ssl.ca;
                ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
                ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
                ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';

                add_header Accept-Ranges bytes;
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
                add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000" always;
                add_header Public-Key-Pins 'pin-sha256="Niasdcu1LQAzCK234v6aJLcwJFCcWATc4asdIBhio7XpIQ="; pin-sha256="75h33riR+PAtOJcVKNfn2y1/N1ARLqJ213YDX5bnAi1Q="; max-age=2592000;';
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at your redirect server block... Since *WordPress* isn't going to allow or like the fact that you use both www and root domain for website url, you must choose one. Let's assume you don't want the www and want to use the domain itself, your **first** redirect server block would look like this:

```
server {
    listen 161.122.20.14;
    server_name blog.domain.com www.blog.domain.com;
    return 301 https://blog.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

This would effectively listen on the given ip, port 80 for both blog.domain.com and www.blog.domain.com redirecting them to https://blog.domain.com

Now why did i say **first**? Because you might want to have another redirect server block to catch all https at www domain. In this case, you need to make sure your server block has valid ssl config set. Without more investigating and only taking fron your config, your ssl redirect would look like this:

```
server {
    listen 161.122.20.14:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.blog.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/ssl.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/ssl.key;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/ssl.ca;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';

    return 301 https://blog.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

now that we are certain that all requests to either blog.domain.com or www.blog.domain.com are being taken care of as far as redirection, on both port 80 and 443, our main server block would look like so:

```
server {
    listen 161.122.20.14:443 ssl http2 deferred;
    server_name blog.domain.com;

    root /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    access_log /var/log/virtualmin/blog.domain.com_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/virtualmin/blog.domain.com_error_log;

    ssl_certificate /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/ssl.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/ssl.key;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /home/domain/domains/blog.domain.com/ssl.ca;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';

    add_header Accept-Ranges bytes;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000" always;
    add_header Public-Key-Pins 'pin-sha256="Niasdcu1LQAzCK234v6aJLcwJFCcWATc4asdIBhio7XpIQ="; pin-sha256="75h33riR+PAtOJcVKNfn2y1/N1ARLqJ213YDX5bnAi1Q="; max-age=2592000;';

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires 365d;
    }

    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ {
        return 444;
    }

    location ~* \.(pl|cgi|py|sh|lua)\$ {
        return 444;
    }

    location ~ /(\.|wp-config\.php|readme\.html|license\.txt) { deny all; }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/php-nginx/14765596504348.sock/socket;
    }
}
```

Key here is your try_files and adding a / location block containing the default action. You should also save that php location block and use it for future configurations... the other one was just, how to say, unsecure. This is really, in essence, what will allow you to use permalinks with *WordPress*.

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/php-nginx/14765596504348.sock/socket;
    }
```

I'm also wondering where you got the idea to put all fastcgi params in your config.. where did you get such info?

Mind you i've copy/pasted from what you posted without checking if all was valid.